# Php Include Child Theme directory

Tags: php

I am using this code to return the contents of the php file but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
 <?php include (get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/serv_night.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to include it per URL? Use the normal file sytsem instead.

Comment: ok thnx that worked